# how to get data from html in SQL Server column

Tags: html, sql-server-2008, filtering

I have some html content in a SQL Server column, I want to read the content from the html.

For example:

```
<ektdesignns_choices ektdesignns_nodetype="element" title="How many gigs do you play each month?" ektdesignns_caption="How many gigs do you play each month?" name="ektpoll1303074024421" ektdesignns_name="ektpoll1303074024421" id="ektpoll1303074024421">
  <ol contenteditable="false" onkeypress="design_validate_choice(1, -1, this, 'Options are required.')" onclick="design_validate_choice(1, -1, this, 'Options are required.')" onblur="design_validate_choice(1, -1, this, 'Options are required.')" ektdesignns_validation="choice-req" ektdesignns_maxoccurs="1" ektdesignns_minoccurs="1" unselectable="on" title="How many gigs do you play each month?" class="design_list_vertical">
    <li>
      <input type="radio" ektdesignns_nodetype="item" name="ektpoll1303074024421" value="1 or fewer_1" title="1 or fewer" id="ID2504263" />
      <label contenteditable="true" unselectable="off" for="ID2504263">1 or fewer</label>
    </li>
    <li>
       <input type="radio" ektdesignns_nodetype="item" name="ektpoll1303074024421" value="2-4_2" title="2-4" id="ID5115606" />
       <label contenteditable="true" unselectable="off" for="ID5115606">2-4</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="radio" ektdesignns_nodetype="item" name="ektpoll1303074024421" value="5-7_3" title="5-7" id="ID477116" />
        <label contenteditable="true" unselectable="off" for="ID477116">5-7</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="radio" ektdesignns_nodetype="item" name="ektpoll1303074024421" value="8 or more_4" title="8 or more" id="ID5515606" />
        <label contenteditable="true" unselectable="off" for="ID5515606">8 or more</label>
    </li>
  </ol>
</ektdesignns_choices><input type="submit" value="Vote" />
```

I want read all the labels in this html. Anyone have any idea, how shall I go about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your HTML is indeed XHTML compliant, and if you have the HTML stored in a `XML` column in your SQL Server table, then you could retrieve your labels from it in T-SQL using XQuery:

```
DECLARE @HtmlTbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY, Html XML)

INSERT INTO @HtmlTbl(Html) VALUES('<ektdesignns_choices ektdesignns_nodetype="element" title="How many gigs do you play each month?" ektdesignns_caption="How many gigs do you play each month?" name="ektpoll1303074024421" ektdesignns_name="ektpoll1303074024421" id="ektpoll1303074024421">
  <ol contenteditable="false" onkeypress="design_validate_choice(1, -1, this, ''Options are required.'')" onclick="design_validate_choice(1, -1, this, ''Options are required.'')" onblur="design_validate_choice(1, -1, this, ''Options are required.'')" ektdesignns_validation="choice-req" ektdesignns_maxoccurs="1" ektdesignns_minoccurs="1" unselectable="on" title="How many gigs do you play each month?" class="design_list_vertical">
    <li>
      <input type="radio" ektdesignns_nodetype="item" name="ektpoll1303074024421" value="1 or fewer_1" title="1 or fewer" id="ID2504263" />
      <label contenteditable="true" unselectable="off" for="ID2504263">1 or fewer</label>
    </li>
    <li>
       <input type="radio" ektdesignns_nodetype="item" name="ektpoll1303074024421" value="2-4_2" title="2-4" id="ID5115606" />
       <label contenteditable="true" unselectable="off" for="ID5115606">2-4</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="radio" ektdesignns_nodetype="item" name="ektpoll1303074024421" value="5-7_3" title="5-7" id="ID477116" />
        <label contenteditable="true" unselectable="off" for="ID477116">5-7</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="radio" ektdesignns_nodetype="item" name="ektpoll1303074024421" value="8 or more_4" title="8 or more" id="ID5515606" />
        <label contenteditable="true" unselectable="off" for="ID5515606">8 or more</label>
    </li>
  </ol></ektdesignns_choices><input type="submit" value="Vote" />')
```

This will retrieve all `<label>` elements from your (X)Html as a single XML string:

```
SELECT
    Html.query('//label')
FROM @HtmlTbl 
WHERE ID = 1
```

Output:

```
<label contenteditable="true" unselectable="off" for="ID2504263">1 or fewer</label>
<label contenteditable="true" unselectable="off" for="ID5115606">2-4</label>
<label contenteditable="true" unselectable="off" for="ID477116">5-7</label>
<label contenteditable="true" unselectable="off" for="ID5515606">8 or more</label>
```

Or this will select all the contents of the `<label>` tags, one per row:

```
SELECT
    C.value('(.)[1]', 'varchar(1000)')
FROM @HtmlTbl 
CROSS APPLY Html.nodes('//label') AS T(C)
WHERE ID = 1
```

Output:

```
1 or fewer
2-4
5-7
8 or more
```

Answer (score 0):

Pull the data from the DB and then use an HTML parser to pull out the information you want. It will make your life *much* easier.

Whatever you do, please *don't* try to use RegExs unless you are *only* looking for data that matches a regular expression. (since HTML is not a regular language, it often causes more problems than it solves)

Answer (score 0):

If all HTML you have is as well formed as this one you can cast it to XML and use some XQuery to find the label nodes,

```
select T.N.value('.', 'nvarchar(100)')
from Table
    cross apply XMLCol.nodes('//label') as T(N)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use PATINDEX and SUBSTRING if you want to extract a value from a well defined tag

```
 /*
    <HTML><head><meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0'>
    </head>
    <BODY onload='document.frmLaunch.submit();'> Redirecting... 
    <FORM name='frmLaunch' method='POST' action='https://acsabsatest.bankserv.co.za/mdpayacs/pareq'>
    <input type=hidden name='PaReq' value='eJxVUctuwjAQ/JWID8jaJjy1tRRKJXKg4iWQuLnOtkSUJDgJ0H597ZCU9pSZ2ex4dxY3B0M0XZOuDEmcU1GoD/KS+KmzWC1HnHWDHu9IXIQrOku8kCmSLJXcZ75AaKntM/qg0lKi0udJ9Co55wgNxhOZaCq56CLcIabqRHKi0mNB5hK+m0Qrr/VAqKuosyotzZcccIbQEqzMpzyUZV6MAa7Xq//WmPg6878VgqsjPOZZVA4V1u+WxHK3iWfrlzlf87lYH6NgyfP9bhvddtvwCcH9gbEqSQrGRywQgceGYz4aswCh1lGd3CByH6484TM7WCNg7t4J70S4wl8BbbqGUt0u0zKkW56l5FoQfjHGVGi7RPN5bPA8c/nq0iY47AeDXn9Qh1wLziqxAQnOerWXIwiuBZrjQXNdi/5d/Qf60asq'>
    <input type=hidden name='TermUrl' value='http://TermUrl'>
    <input type=hidden name='MD' value='469695'></FORM></BODY></HTML>
    */
--Find the start of the tag
    SELECT PATINDEX('%<input type=hidden name=''PaReq'' value=%', @webViewData); 
--(Answer is 246)
-->Find the end of the tag
    SELECT PATINDEX('%''>%', substring(@webViewData,PATINDEX('%<input type=hidden name=''PaReq'' value=%', @webViewData),len(@webViewData))); 
--(Answer is 468)
--Get the value content of the tag
    select substring(@webViewData,246+39,468-40)
--Everything combined:
    select substring(@webViewData,PATINDEX('%<input type=hidden name=''PaReq'' value=%', @webViewData)+39,PATINDEX('%''>%', substring(@webViewData,PATINDEX('%<input type=hidden name=''PaReq'' value=%', @webViewData),len(@webViewData)))-40)
```