# MSSQL read tags from XHTML stored as XML column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have stored a ~500kb ~10k lines XHTML document as XML datatype. Now I want to extract data from a single table in this document. There seem to be a lot of ways to deal with XML structured data, the most promissing solution (I tried others) seemed to be:
[how to get data from html in SQL Server column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8826130/how-to-get-data-from-html-in-sql-server-column)

When I run this testcode:

```
DECLARE @HtmlTbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY, Html XML)

INSERT INTO @HtmlTbl(Html) VALUES('
<html>
  <head>
    <title>asdf</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
')

SELECT  html.query('//title')
FROM    @HtmlTbl 
WHERE   ID = 1
```

it works pretty well. But if my XHTML looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO @HtmlTbl(Html) VALUES('
<html xmlns="../www.w3.org/1999/xhtml/index.html">
  <head>
    <title>asdf</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
')
```

it is already failing and I'm getting empty strings as result. Of course my original XHTML file is much larger and I don't want to run in all those comments and stuff to cause my search to fail.

I'm new to handling XML in MSSQL, maybe someone can tell me a better way to extract the table I'm looking for. The server has SQL Express 2014, thx for help.